# check if button has focus

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a text box and i am doing some validation on blur event of textbox. I also have button.

Currently my textbox shows validation and sets the focus back to it. But what i want is to not show me message when i click on button.

In simple words i dont want to have validation when button is clicked after textbox loses its focus

I tried to check if button has focus using this `document.activeelement` but that returns me body

here is my html

```
<input id="txtName" data-bind ="event: { blur: $root.check1 }" />
<button  id="btnSubmit" class="btn"  data-bind="click: check2" > Submit </button>
```

here is my viewmodel

```
var viewModel = {

 };


viewModel.check1 = function(){
    alert("duplicate name not allowed");
     $("[id$=txtName]").focus();
                    return;
}

viewModel.check2 = function(){
    alert("alert from button click");
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3uNP/139/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just delay the check1 logic to check which element get the focus:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u3uNP/140/)

```
viewModel.check1 = function (e) {
    $("[id$=txtName]").dequeue().delay(0).queue(function () {
        if(document.activeElement === $('#btnSubmit')[0]) return;
        alert("duplicate name not allowed");
        $(this).focus();
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: but now i dont get alert when i leave textbox

Comment: Check in jsfiddle, i get `duplicate name not allowed` when leaving textbox and not button focused, tested on chrome. Isn't it what you are expecting?

Comment: wow thats amazing. I will do some more checks and accept answer. Will it be ok?

Comment: Super duper stuff this is . I didnt imagined if this is even possible. Great thanks.